# iOS - Optimize and save PNG. Indexing PNG's at runtime (quantization)

Tags: ios, uiimage, png, core-graphics, libpng

I would like to optimize my PNG's before saving them. Indexed PNGs take up much less space. I have tried using the `libimagequant` library but without success. I'm stuck at saving the results to a file or using it to transfer to a server via HTTP.

This is my code:

```
CGImageRef imageRef2 = [cutPicture CGImage];
NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef2);
NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef2);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
CGContextRef context2 = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                             bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

CGContextDrawImage(context2, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef2);
CGContextRelease(context2);

// Create an 8-bit palette for the bitmap via libimagequant (http://pngquant.org/lib)
liq_attr *liqAttr = liq_attr_create();
liq_image *liqImage = liq_image_create_rgba(liqAttr, rawData, (int)imageSize, (int)imageSize, 0);
liq_result *liqRes = liq_quantize_image(liqAttr, liqImage);

liq_error e = liq_write_remapped_image(liqRes, liqImage, rawData, 4 * imageSize * imageSize);
const liq_palette *liqPal = liq_get_palette(liqRes);

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawData length:4 * imageSize * imageSize];

NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo.png"]];
[data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];

// Transpose the result into an rgba array
unsigned char colorTable[1024];
for (NSInteger n = 0; n < liqPal->count; n++) {
    colorTable[4 * n] = liqPal->entries[n].r;
    colorTable[4 * n + 1] = liqPal->entries[n].g;
    colorTable[4 * n + 2] = liqPal->entries[n].b;
    colorTable[4 * n + 3] = liqPal->entries[n].a;
}

// Release
liq_attr_destroy(liqAttr);
liq_image_destroy(liqImage);
liq_result_destroy(liqRes);
```

But the output data is 5-6 megs which is not what i wanted. I do realize that my saving code is wrong but I'm not sure how to do it and I'm also not sure whether or not I'm using `libimagequant` correctly.
Maybe there is a better format or way to perserve transparency and keep the file size small.? I will use the file to save it to the gallery as well as send it to a remote host via HTTP.

Comment: If they are 5-6 megs they are likely to be photos not line art.  Did you consider using JPEG instead of PNG?  If you can accept the loss due to quantization to 256 colors you could probably also accept the lossy compression to JPEG.  There would be an issue if you are using transparency, though.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @GlennRanders-Pehrson, but transparency is vital in this case, so unfortunately i can't go with JPEG. :( And yes, they are photos.